# Remove non numeric values from a Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas Series containing multiple different datatypes. I want to filter out all elements which are not numeric. The resulting Series should only contain floats or ints.

Is there a simple way to filter the Series? Most solutions I found only worked with DataFrames.

Comment: What do you mean by the fields?

Comment: I edited my question. I meant elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [43]: s
Out[43]:
0       0
1       1
2    str1
3     NaN
4       3
5       5
6    str2
7       4
8     NaN
dtype: object
```

convert to numeric:

```
In [44]: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
Out[44]:
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    3.0
5    5.0
6    NaN
7    4.0
8    NaN
dtype: float64
```

drop NaNs:

```
In [45]: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').dropna()
Out[45]:
0    0.0
1    1.0
4    3.0
5    5.0
7    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, `pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').dropna()` did it!

Comment: @fwind, glad to help