# python plotting data from excel csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv, plot

my excel file is saved as a csv. It has three columns and I am trying to plot column 1 vs column 2 and column 1 vs column 3 on the same plot. I am able to separate the three columns into separate variables, but for some reason cannot plot it. Only the X and Y axis shows up, but no actual graph. Do you know how to plot it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('file:///C:/Users/Avalanche/Documents/data/FL20data/FL20BU%2317.H-Transfer.1 cycle_data.csv', skiprows = 1)
Htran = data.head(1201)
colm1 = Htran.loc[: , "H-Transfer.1 cycle.Field (Oe)"]
colm2 = Htran.loc[: , "H-Transfer.1 cycle.F1"]
colm3 = Htran.loc[: , "H-Transfer.1 cycle.R1"] 
plt.plot([colm1], [colm2])
plt.plot([colm1], [colm3])
plt.xlim(-3500,3500)
plt.ylim(2400,2600)
plt.title('R vs. H')
plt.xlabel('H (Oe)')
plt.ylabel('Resistance')
plt.show()
```

DATA: (I made sure to skip the first row in my code)

```
(1-5)R6C10  FL20BU-17   Failed: NONE Passed: skipgrade;

H-Transfer.1 cycle.Field (Oe)   H-Transfer.1 cycle.F1   H-Transfer.1 cycle.R1

-3000.3 2487.508    2487.508
-2994.7 2492.037    2487.508
-2989.9 2510.315    2496.582
-2985.1 2478.497    2505.721
-2980.3 2478.497    2496.582
-2974.7 2496.582    2514.925
-2969.9 2474.016    2524.195
-2965.2 2496.582    2482.995
-2960.4 2501.143    2487.508
-2954.8 2501.143    2478.497
-2950   2501.143    2505.721
```

Comment: what is your current output? blank or just not the correct graph?

Comment: It is just a blank graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `plt.plot([colm1], [colm2])` is a bad idea: you are wrapping a pandas series in a list and then trying to plot it, which is generally not going to work. Second, you likely just want an array of values rather than a pandas series, so tack on the `.values` attribute to just get the values.

Assuming you have your dataframe is made up of numerical data, this should work for you.

```
colm1 = Htran.loc[: , "H-Transfer.1 cycle.Field (Oe)"].values
colm2 = Htran.loc[: , "H-Transfer.1 cycle.F1"].values
colm3 = Htran.loc[: , "H-Transfer.1 cycle.R1"].values
plt.plot(colm1, colm2)
plt.plot(colm1, colm3)
```

As an aside, I recommend looking through the pandas documentation on plotting. Lots of useful information: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Comment: when i add '.values' to the end, the error is "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'' and both of the axis go from 0 to 1. Do i need to add something else besides the '.values'

Comment: @nrav999 No I don't think you should have to, but this makes me think you have non-numeric data in your dataframe. Could you add the first 5-10 rows of your data to your question?

Comment: I added the data into the question

Comment: Hmm looks like numeric data to me, but maybe there are non-numeric data hidden elsewhere. To be sure, you could convert the series using `pd.to_numeric()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36970519/5285918).